# I started to make selenium scripts browse in New Relic, and when i try to print a Attribute i cant get this data

Tags: selenium, newrelic, newrelic-synthetics

Script:
[image]

Output:

ManagedPromise {
flow_:
ControlFlow {
propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
activeQueue_:
TaskQueue {
name_: 'TaskQueue::3218',
flow_: [Circular],
tasks_: [Array],
interrupts_: null,
pending_: null,
subQ_: null,
state_: 'new',
unhandledRejections_: Set {} },
taskQueues_: Set { [TaskQueue], [TaskQueue] },
shutdownTask_: null,
hold_:
Timeout {
*called: false,
*idleTimeout: 2147483647,
*idlePrev: [TimersList],
*idleNext: [TimersList],
*idleStart: 598,
*onTimeout: [Function],
*timerArgs: undefined,
*repeat: 2147483647,
*destroyed: false,
[Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
[Symbol(asyncId)]: 18,
[Symbol(triggerId)]: 1 } },
stack*:
{ Task: WebElement.getAttribute(id)
at Driver.schedule (/opt/runtimes/4.0.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
at WebElement.schedule* (/opt/runtimes/4.0.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2010:25)
at WebElement.getAttribute (/opt/runtimes/4.0.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2263:17)
at eval (eval at JobResource.getScriptFn (/opt/runtimes/4.0.0/modules/synthetics-runner/lib/job-resource/index.js:79:19), :64:37)
at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback* (/opt/runtimes/4.0.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
at TaskQueue.execute* (/opt/runtimes/4.0.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
at TaskQueue.executeNext* (/opt/runtimes/4.0.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
at asyncRun (/opt/runtimes/4.0.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
at /opt/runtimes/4.0.0/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
at process.*tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'Task' },
parent*: null,
callbacks*: null,
state*: 'pending',
handled*: false,
value*: undefined,
queue_: null }

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for Selenium's WebElement Node API here:

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html

We can see that getAttribute returns a promise rather than the data object you're expecting. This is also reflected in the logs that you shared Script:

```
Output:
ManagedPromise {... etc}
```

So the way to extract the data from the promise is we have to wait for the promise to resolve. You can do with by adding a `then` chain to the promise.

```
element.getAttribute('id').then((data)=>{
console.log(data);
})
```